# IIS expired certificated on autosign certificate

Tags: iis

I'm new of IIS website ...
on windows 2016 standard ed. SO...my site has expired the autosign certified.
I create a new autosign and i Haven't delete the old certificate...
I clear the client cache..but it continues to see only the old expired certificate...
is there someone that knows the cause?
best regards

---

Impossibile raggiungere il sitoLa pagina web all'indirizzo https://8******/TEWeb potrebbe essere temporaneamente non disponibile oppure è stata permanentemente spostata a un nuovo indirizzo web.
ERR_SSL_KEY_USAGE_INCOMPATIBLE

---

I would understand how bypassing this problem

Comment: https://docs.jexusmanager.com/tutorials/https-binding.html Certificates are bind to IIS sites via Windows HTTP API, so you should review if the mapping isn't proper.

Comment: Certificate renewal takes time. Do you still see only the old expired certificate on the client? If so, please try restarting your server and try again.

Comment: ok I try to restart the server

Comment: Hi i restart but nothing changes i have the same problem the client sees only the old expired certificate...

Comment: I delete the old expired certificate i restart the machine but there is always the problem

Comment: Hi the problem was the binding that points to old certificate but my site have problem to accept a new certificate...on edge and chrome doesn't go while on mozilla it  goes in...

Comment: ERR_SSL_KEY_USAGE_INCOMPATIBLE

Comment: i resolve ...this link is important...

Comment: https://www.frameflow.com/blog/solving-chrome-err-ssl-key-usage-incompatible/